# curl command in java

Tags: java, curl

First of all , i've already seen couple of documents, stackoverflow questions regarding the same ..I've my project specific question
When trying to run command :

```
   curl -u username:password https://example.com/xyz/abc
```

from the mac terminal , I get my desired json format data.
But running the same command from java code , I get Unauthorised 401 error in console.
My code is :

```
    String username="myusername";
    String password="mypassword";
    String url="https://www.example.com/xyz/abc";
       String[] command = {"curl", "-u" ,"Accept:application/json", username, ":" , password , url};
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
        Process p;
        try
        {
            p = process.start();
             BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                String result = builder.toString();
                System.out.print(result);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {   System.out.print("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get Unauthorised 401 error and bunch of html tags .
It seems like a repetitive question, but I've tried all the approaches.
I know alternative is using http response method, but particularly I want to use curl commands.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
String[] command = {"curl", "-u" ,"Accept:application/json", username, ":" , password , url};
```

into

```
String[] command = {"curl", "-H", "Accept:application/json", "-u", username+":"+password , url};
```

Comment: no problem, my first  version lacked -H flag, making the query's syntax invalid

Answer (score 1):

hey try this I had the same problem.
It worked in my terminal had the same error as yours.

```
String[] command = {"curl", "-u" , username+ ":" + password , url};
```