# Wap push message over http

Tags: android, http, push, wap

I want to send a wap push message which contains a URL to my android mobile & I want to see how it popups....

[This is the URL I use](http://172.16.10.20:13002/?PhoneNumber=761969807&WAPURL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049555/curl-command-in-java&Text=abc%20def%20ghi).

It gives this error in my linux screen.

> 2019-01-28 13:25:15 [31965] [9] INFO: Box connection tried from denied host <172.16.20.77>, disconnected
>   2019-01-28 13:25:15 [31965] [9] ERROR: Failed to create new boxc connection.

What can I do? Any help is welcome!!!

Comment: NOW THE CONNECTION IS OKAY.      2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [9] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1> 
2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [9] DEBUG: Started thread 25 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function)
2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [25] DEBUG: Thread 25 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) maps to pid 31965.
2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [25] DEBUG: setting up systems for new wapbox
2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [25] DEBUG: Started thread 26 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender)
2019-01-28 13:51:42 [31965] [26] DEBUG: Thread 26 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) maps to pid 31965.

Comment: I am using kannel